# Wireless card not detected on Dell XPS 13

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

Just got a dell XPS 13 which was preinstalled window 10. I like Ubuntu, therefore, delete Windows 10, and managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it. But, I cannot let it connect to the internet. Some information may be useful as follows:

Dell XPS 13 
(which cannot use cable to connect the internet);
Broadcom bcm4352 802.11ac 14e4:43b1;
Ubuntu 14.04.

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here you have two solutions available to make your Wi-Fi card work properly :

1. Install Ubuntu 15.04 which contain a lot of fixes and has Wi-Fi working out of the box. If you want to do that I have written a complete step-by-step guide [here](http://hgdev.co/installing-ubuntu-15-04-on-the-dell-xps-13-9343-2015-a-complete-guide-update/).
2. Keep your Ubuntu 14.04 installation and install needed packages to make Wi-Fi works. Here is how :

   1. Download on a USB key the followings packages : [bcml-kernel-source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source), [dkms](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/dkms), [fakeroot](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/fakeroot) and [libfakeroot](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libfakeroot).
   2. Install them by running :

      ```
      sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
      sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*.deb
      ```

      After that your Wi-Fi should work properly.

---

I know that is not the question but I encourage you to install 15.04. You will have a lot less trouble to make everything work properly.

Comment: Thanks hg8, the second one works :-)
the fakeroot and libfakeroot may not be necessary, i only installed the rest 2 ones, and it also works. 
One more thing is to download the latest ones, in case something may went wrong for the high versions of Ubuntu kernel.

Comment: Perfect! Glad it helped =)

Comment: 15.04 does not have ANY fixes related to wifi compared to 14.04.3.